# ¿Como pasar datos de DataGrid a DataGrid?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

estamos realizando un proyecto y somos novatos en este ámbito, lo que estamos intentado hacer es pasar la información que contiene un "DataGrid" hacia otro que esté en un formulario distinto, los datos los tenemos almacenados en una ArrayList y se muestran en el DataGrid inicial.

Comment: Lectura obligatoria: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Comment: Por favor, comparte el código que has intentado hasta el momento y lee como realizar una buena pregunta para que algún compañero pueda ayudarte de la mejor manera posible. Dejo aquí el enlace: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer   . Gracias